# Replace 1st column records from 2nd Columns Record

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two columns in Oracle in two different data. For example : my 1st column name is "FROM" and second column is "TO".

```
From    TO
Bhx      ACE
Ace      BHX
LTN      PRA
PRA      LTN
lba      agp
agp      lba
man      ssh
ssh      man
lgw       tfs
tfs       lgw
```

WHAT I WANT: if "TO" columns is "BHX,  LTN , LBA, LGW, MAN " then column "from" replace column "to" records... is there any way in Oracle query.

Output result :

```
   Bhx      ACE
   bhx      BHX
   LTN      PRA
   ltn      LTN
   lba      agp
   lba      lba
   man      ssh
   man      man
   lgw      tfs
   lgw      lgw
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT "From" ,case when "TO" in ('BHX', 'LTN' , 'LBA', 'LGW', 'MAN') then "From" else "To" end "To"
```

`Case` expression with `IN` allow you to check different values of your TO column, if they are sames, it uses From column , if not, it uses To column.

Answer (score 1):

Just select them with the opposite aliases:

```
SELECT "To" AS "From", "From" AS "To"
FROM   my_table
```

BTW - "from" is a reserved word in SQL. Although it's possible to work around this (e.g., by using quotes), it's a poor choice for a column's name, and you should probably find a different one.

Comment: NO u didnt get me lik from ACE to BHX

Comment: @CricBuzz Please post your expected output. It's impossible to understand the question as it's currently phrased.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
  SET From =To,
  SET To = From
   WHERE TO IN ('BHX', 'LTN' , 'LBA', 'LGW', 'MAN')
```